# subtract but give parameter, which should not be deleted

Tags: list, prolog

I want to use the predicate `subtract` to remove all list items that are not lists.

Sample query showing the expected answer:

```
?- subtract([1,2,[3],[],4,5,[8]], ..., Xs).
Xs = [[3],[],[8]].
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: If a variable, `X`, can *unify* with `[_|_]` or `[]`, then `X` is a list. SWI prolog also has a built-in, `is_list(X)` which succeeds if `X` is a list. You should use this information to figure out how you an write this predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  `tfilter/3` together with the reified test predicate `nil_or_cons_t/2`: it's monotonic!

```
nil_or_cons_t(Xs,T) :-
   (  nonvar(Xs)
   -> (  nil_or_cons(Xs)
      -> T = true
      ;  T = false
      )
   ;  T = true , nil_or_cons(Xs)
   ;  T = false, freeze(Xs,\+nil_or_cons(Xs))
   ).

nil_or_cons([]).
nil_or_cons([_|_]).
```

Sample query:

```
?- tfilter(nil_or_cons_t, [1,2,[3],[],4,5,[8]], Lss).
Lss = [[3],[],[8]].
```

#### Edit

This answer is incorrect (too general = "test predicate too simplistic").

Please see my follow up answer for details.

Comment: This `freeze(Xs, \+nil_or_cons(Xs))` would deserve to be expressed in a cleaner manner, but for the time being, that is the best we can get.

Answer (score 1):

My [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322685/4609915) was clearly incorrect.

Why? It classified terms like `[_|non_list]` as *lists*... Bad!

How come? The *non-recursive* `nil_or_cons_t/2` can be too shallow.

What to do? Use the *recursive* [reified predicate `list_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618820/4609915) instead!

Comment: Not necessarily so. We often accept generalizations, think of differences, think of the second and third argument of `append/3.` The precise circumstances for admissible generalizations are not that evident. An easy way to check is to ask why `nil_or_cons_t(_,_).` is an inadmissible generalization.