# How do I rewrite the following so it uses if_?

Tags: prolog

I am doing some easy [exercises](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) to get a feel for the language.

```
is_list([]).
is_list([_|_]).

my_flatten([],[]).
my_flatten([X|Xs],RR) :-
   my_flatten(Xs,R),
   (is_list(X), !, append(X,R,RR); RR = [X | R]).
```

Here is a version using cut, for a predicate that flattens a list one level.

```
my_flatten([],[]).
my_flatten([X|Xs],RR) :-
   my_flatten(Xs,R),
   if_(is_list(X), append(X,R,RR), RR = [X | R]).
```

Here is how I want to write it, but it does not work. Neither does `is_list(X) = true` as the `if_` condition. How am I intended to use `if_` here?

Comment: Where is `if_` defined?

Comment: I've been going through [Power Of Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/metapredicates#if_3) so I got the reif library from the link and put it into main library directory by hand.

Comment: I am using SWI Prolog.

Comment: but that is for *reification* constraints. So that would mean that the `is_list` predicate would have *two* parameters, and as a second a boolean.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then it would be fine to use what you showed me here. As the newcomer to this, I do not really understand all the arguments why the other constructs are flawed, but it did impress upon me that I should avoid things like cut whenever necessary. Since the regular if is fine here, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog, the equivalen of an `if … then … else …` in other languages is:

```
(condition -> if-true; if-false)
```

With *`condition`*, *`if-true`* and *`if-false`* items you need to fill in.

So in this specific case, you can implement this with:

```
my_flatten([],[]).
my_flatten([X|Xs],RR) :- 
    my_flatten(Xs,R),
    (  is_list(X)
    -> append(X,R,RR)
    ; RR = [X | R] ).
```

or we can flatten recursively with:

```
my_flatten([],[]).
my_flatten([X|Xs],RR) :- 
    my_flatten(Xs,R),
    (  flatten(X, XF)
    -> append(XF,R,RR)
    ; RR = [X | R] ).
```

Your [**`if_/3`** predicate](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/metapredicates#if_3) is used for [*reified predicates*](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-reification-predicates).

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry, I somewhat skipped this)

- Please refer to [P07](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Emeidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/). It clearly states that it flattens out `[a, [b, [c, d], e]]`, but you and @Willem produce:

```
    ?- my_flatten([a, [b, [c, d], e]], X).
       X = [a,b,[c,d],e].   % not flattened!
```

- And the solution given there succeeds for

```
    ?- my_flatten(non_list, X).
       X = [non_list].      % unexpected, nothing to flatten
```

- Your definition of `is_list/1` succeeds for `is_list([a|non_list])`.  Commonly, we want this to fail.

What you need is a safe predicate to test for lists. So let's concentrate on that first:

What is wrong with `is_list/1` and if-then-else?  It is as non-monotonic, as [many other impure type testing predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27306453/772868).

```
?- Xs = [], is_list([a|Xs]).
   Xs = [].
?- is_list([a|Xs]).     % generalization, Xs = [] removed
   false.                  % ?!? unexpected
```

While the original query succeeds correctly, a generalization of it unexpectedly fails.  In the monotonic part of Prolog, we expect that a generalization will succeed (or loop, produce an error, use up all resources, but never ever fail).

You have now two options to improve upon this highly undesirable situation:

### Stay safe with safe inferences, `_si`!

Just take the definition of [`list_si/1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600104/772868) in place of `is_list/1`. In problematic situations, your program will now abort with an instantiation error, meaning "well sorry, I don't know how to answer this query". Be happy for that response! You are saved from being misled by incorrect answers.

In other words: There is nothing wrong with `( If_0 -> Then_0 ; Else_0 )`, as long as the `If_0` handles the situation of insufficient instantiations correctly (and does not refer to a user defined program since otherwise you will be again in non-monotonic behavior).

Here is such a definition:

```
my_flatten(Es, Fs) :-
   list_si(Es),
   phrase(flattenl(Es), Fs).

flattenl([]) --> [].
flattenl([E|Es]) -->
   ( {list_si(E)} -> flattenl(E) ;  [E] ),
   flattenl(Es).

?- my_flatten([a, [b, [c, d], e]], X).
   X = [a,b,c,d,e].
```

So `( If_0 -> Then_0 ; Else_0 )` has two weaknesses: The condition `If_0` might be sensible to insufficient instantiations, and the `Else_0` may be the source of non-monotonicity. But otherwise it works. So why do we want more than that?
In many more general situations this definition will now bark back: "Instantiation error"!  While not incorrect, this still can be improved. This exercise is not the ideal example for this, but we will give it a try.

### Use a reified condition

In order to use `if_/3` you need a reified condition, that is, a definition that carries it's truth value as an explicit extra argument. Let's call it `list_t/2`.

```
?- list_t([a,b,c], T).
   T = true.
?- list_t([a,b,c|non_list], T).
   T = false.
?- list_t(Any, T).
   Any = [],
   T = true
;  T = false,
   dif(Any,[]),
   when(nonvar(Any),Any\=[_|_])
;  Any = [_],
   T = true
;  Any = [_|_Any1],
   T = false,
   dif(_Any1,[]),
   when(nonvar(_Any1),_Any1\=[_|_])
;  ... .
```

So `list_t` can also be used to enumerate all `true` and `false` situations.  Let's go through them:

1. `T = true, Any = []` that's the empty list
2. `T = false, dif(Any, []), Any is not [_|_]` note how this inequality uses `when/2`
3. `T = true, Any = [_]` that's all lists with one element
4. `T = true, Any = [_|_Any1] ...` meaning: we start with an element, but then no list

```
list_t(Es, T) :-
   if_( Es = []
      , T = true
      , if_(nocons_t(Es), T = false, ( Es = [_|Fs], list_t(Fs, T) ) )
      ).

nocons_t(NC, T) :-
   (  NC \= [_|_] -> T = true
   ;  nonvar(NC) -> T = false
   ;  /* var(NC) -> */ freeze(NC, NC \= [_|_], T = true
   ;  NC = [_|_], T = false
   ).
```

So finally, the reified definition:

```
:- meta_predicate( if_(1, 2, 2, ?,?) ).

my_flatten(Es, Fs) :-
   phrase(flattenl(Es), Fs).

flattenl([]) --> [].
flattenl([E|Es]) -->
   if_(list_t(E), flattenl(E), [E] ),
   flattenl(Es).

if_(C_1, Then__0, Else__0, Xs0,Xs) :-
   if_(C_1, phrase(Then__0, Xs0,Xs), phrase(Else__0, Xs0,Xs) ).

?- my_flatten([a|_], [e|_]).
   false.
?- my_flatten([e|_], [e|_]).
   true
;  true
;  true
;  ... .
?- my_flatten([a|Xs], [a]).
   Xs = []
;  Xs = [[]]
;  Xs = [[],[]]
;  ... .
?- my_flatten([X,a], [a]).
   X = []
;  X = [[]]
;  X = [[[]]]
;  X = [[[[]]]]
;  ... .
?- my_flatten(Xs, [a]).
   loops. % at least it does not fail
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
myflat([], []).

myflat([H|T], L) :-
  myflat(H, L1),
  myflat(T, L2),
  append(L1, L2, L).

myflat(L, [L]).
```

Comment: `myflat([[[1]]],L).` gives 15 answers describing 10 solutions. To my understanding, there should be only one solution: `X = [1]`