# Show that Y is the list you get when you flatten X (Prolog)

Tags: list, prolog

First of all: I'm a newbie when it comes to Prolog, I just wrote my first lines yesterday.

I got the following assignment: Write a rule `flatten(X,Y)`, which is *true* when

- X is a list of lists.
- Y is the list you get when you flatten X.

For example: `flatten([[1,2,3],[],[3,4]], [1,2,3,3,4])` outputs *"true"*.

My general idea was to take the first element of the first list from X and compare it to the first element of Y. But I don't really know how exactly I would do that...

Comment: `flatten( [[A|B] | C], D ) :- flatten( [A, B | C], D ).` is one rule of several that together would define such a predicate. do you understand this syntax and its meaning? if not, some tutorial studying is in order.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was just looking around for some sites for that tutorial studying you suggested. Now, I've taken your rule and put it in my program, with a simple flatten([], []). in front and it works. I am not 100% sure how exactly it works, but I'm currently trying to figure it out. :p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, [mcve].

Comment: The name `flatten/2` is commonly used for flattening arbitrarily nested lists. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618820/772868) in case you want `flatten([[[[1]]]],[1])` to be true.